# refresh div content in Microsoft webmatrix

Tags: jquery, webmatrix-2

I have been trying to implement div refresh in Microsoft Webmatrix environment. I'm preparing cshtml webpage.
I use following code:

```
@{
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(function(){
    setInterval("my_function();",1000); 
    function my_function(){
    $("#refresh").load(location.href + '#time');
    }
  </script>
</head>  
<body>
   <div id="refresh">  
    <div id="time"> Today is @DateTime.Now </div>  
   </div>
</body>
```

unfortunately it does not works. it do not refresh the actual time in 'time' div. where is my mistake in the code?
Best regards Artur;

Comment: replace `setInterval("my_function();",1000);` with `setInterval(my_function(),1000);`

Comment: unfortunatelly it does not work :-(